# Spring Batch ItemWriteListener and SkipListener doesn't work hand in hand

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am making a POC around Spring Batch `SkipListener` and `ItemWriteListener` because my business demands it and I need that way only. In Spring Batch `ItemWriteListener` and `SkipListener` doesn't work hand in hand it seems to me.

Here is some POC code I developed, but `@BeforeWrite` doesn't save anything into DB.

MySkipListener.java

```
public class MySkipListener implements SkipListener<Integer, Integer> {
    
    @Override
    public void onSkipInRead(Throwable t) {
        System.out.println("@@@MySkipListener| On Skip in Read Error : " + t.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onSkipInWrite(Integer item, Throwable t) {
        System.out.println("@@@MySkipListener | Skipped in write due to : " + t.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onSkipInProcess(Integer item, Throwable t) {
        System.out.println("@@@MySkipListener | Skipped in process due to: " + t.getMessage());
    }
}
```

MyStepListener.java

```
public class MyStepListener implements StepExecutionListener {

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        System.out.println("beforeStep");
    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        System.out.println("afterStep");
        return ExitStatus.COMPLETED;
    }
}
```

MyItemWriteListener.java

```
public class MyItemWriteListener {
    
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    
    @BeforeWrite
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void beforeWrite(List<? extends Integer> items) {
        System.out.println("########### ItemWriteListener | beforeWrite " + items);
        
        // MUST FOR ME to save data into DB here !!!
        jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO `test`.`mytest`(`name`) VALUES( 'A')");
    }
}
```

MyJob.java

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.ListItemReader;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class MyJob {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<Integer> itemReader() {
        return new ListItemReader<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Integer> itemWriter() {
        return items -> {
            for (Integer item : items) {
                if (item.equals(1)) {
                    throw new Exception("No 1 here!");
                }
                System.out.println("item = " + item);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step() {
        return steps.get("step")
                .<Integer, Integer>chunk(5)
                .reader(itemReader())
                .writer(itemWriter())
                .faultTolerant()
                .skip(Exception.class)
                .skipLimit(10)
                .listener(mySkipListener())
                .listener(myStepListener())
                .listener(myItemWriteListener())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobs.get("job")
                .start(step())
                .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public MySkipListener mySkipListener() {
        return new MySkipListener();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public MyStepListener myStepListener() {
        return new MyStepListener();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public MyItemWriteListener myItemWriteListener() {
        return new MyItemWriteListener();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> POC code I developed, but @BeforeWrite doesn't save anything into DB. Any quick help?

The reason for that is explained in the [javadoc of ItemWriteListener](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/ItemWriteListener.html):

```
in fault tolerant scenarios, any transactional work that is done in one of these methods
would be rolled back and not re-applied. Because of this, it is recommended to not perform
any logic using this listener that participates in a transaction.
```

All methods from `ItemWriterListener` and `SkipListener` are executed in the scope of the transaction driven by Spring Batch. `ChunkListener` is what you are looking for (I guess). `ChunkListener#beforeChunk` is called **inside** the transaction whereas `ChunkListener#afterChunk` and `ChunkListener#afterChunkError` are called **outside** the transaction. This is to allow compensating actions to take place in their own transaction if needed. In this case, it is up to you manage the lifecycle of this separate transaction. Here is an excerpt from the javadoc:

```
data access code within this callback will still "participate" in the original transaction
**unless it declares that it runs in its own transaction**.
Hence: Use PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW for any transactional operation that is called from here.
```

Comment: I've already used `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`, but its not working.

Comment: According to your description, you have used it in `ItemWriteListener`, but the answer clearly says that this should be done in a `ChunkListener`.

Comment: Ah, I've not implement the chunk listener in my code, probably I might need to do that.  How these listeners works one after other?

Comment: The chunk listener is called before/after the entire chunk (before read/process/write). The ItemWriteListener is called just before writing items (ie after read listener, process listener). Hence it is called after/before the chunk listener.

Answer (score 0):

It is because when you use `@BeforeWrite` to declare a listener method , it will create a spring AOP proxy [behind the scene](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/5c57ed47b8be4b3419229f0617cba895610ab9bc/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/step/builder/SimpleStepBuilder.java#L287) that wraps this method, but this proxy is not a spring bean so it does not know how to react to `@Transactional` and hence it does not have effect.

Try to implement it with `ItemWriteListener` :

```
@Component
public class MyItemWriteListener implements ItemWriteListener<Integer> {
    
    void beforeWrite(List<Integer> items){


    }
}
```

On the other hands, I will not control the transaction related stuff for the items that require batch processing (i.e object read by `ItemReader`) by my own because `spring-batch` already helps to manage the transaction for them . It already started a new transaction whenever processing a new chunk of item. Managing it by yourself feels like will mess things up related to the rollback things when it retries or skips a failure item.

Comment: Certainly `void beforeWrite(List<Integer> items)` not working ! If I dont use `@BeforeWrite` even call is not going into that class.

Comment: no ideas, it should work. make sure if you really configure the listener for the step.

Comment: Hey Yes I did that, would you like to give a try as whole code already in this post !